# Why does Redis save partial data sets?

Tags: c, redis

**Version**: Redis 5.0.3

In `redis.conf` there is an option to set snapshot period. I set this period as every 5 sec if one value is changed to see the Redis performance when it dumps. I ran two application; one is `redis-server` and the other is `redis-benchmark`.
While I was watching a log, I found out some interesting thing like below.

```
7269:C 27 Feb 2019 14:48:39.463 * RDB: 4535 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:48:39.939 * Background saving terminated with success
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:48:45.085 * 10 changes in 5 seconds. Saving...
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:48:45.187 * Background saving started by pid 7270
7270:C 27 Feb 2019 14:49:00.313 * DB saved on disk
7270:C 27 Feb 2019 14:49:00.401 * RDB: 4535 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:49:00.882 * Background saving terminated with success
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:49:06.011 * 10 changes in 5 seconds. Saving...
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:49:06.114 * Background saving started by pid 7271
7271:C 27 Feb 2019 14:49:21.086 * DB saved on disk
7271:C 27 Feb 2019 14:49:21.173 * RDB: 4534 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:49:21.706 * Background saving terminated with success
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:49:27.048 * 10 changes in 5 seconds. Saving...
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:49:27.155 * Background saving started by pid 7273
7273:C 27 Feb 2019 14:49:42.295 * DB saved on disk
7273:C 27 Feb 2019 14:49:42.382 * RDB: 4529 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:49:42.846 * Background saving terminated with success
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:49:48.023 * 10 changes in 5 seconds. Saving...
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:49:48.126 * Background saving started by pid 7274
7274:C 27 Feb 2019 14:50:05.251 * DB saved on disk
7274:C 27 Feb 2019 14:50:05.367 * RDB: 15 MB of memory used by copy-on-write
7257:M 27 Feb 2019 14:50:05.583 * Background saving terminated with success
```

As you can see, the dumped data has almost same size with others and the last one is even little. The thing that I don't understand is why the size is the same and why the last one has small size. (While the redis is dumping, the client requests `set` operation and the last dump probably means the end of `set` operation and start of `get` operation.)

To find out the reason, I look up the code but still don't know why the number has shown like above.

If you see `rdb.c` in the redis package, you can find this kind of source code.

```c
int rdbSave(char *filename, rdbSaveInfo *rsi) {
    ...
    snprintf(tmpfile, 256, "temp-%d.rdb", (int) getpid());
    fp = fopen(tmpfile, "w");
    ...
    rdbSaveRio(...);
}
```

From my understanding, everytime redis dumps the in-memory data, it should overwrite the previous saved data and this data should be lager than before. However, based on the log, the size is not linearly increased and even it is decreased at the last dump.

Am I missing some part of Redis features?

## Edit

According to the comment, I definitely misinterpreted the logs. However, I still have a question about the performance. When snapshotting happens and if there are private dirty memories, the system saves them into the disk. In this point, based on the Redis dump mechanism, although the system sees the private dirty memory caused by `set` operation and only records this number on the log, it saves the all data from the memory. It means that everytime dumping happens, the size of disk expands and I'm pretty sure that it would lead to worse performance. But, when I see the result of benchmark, I can see the same performance drop despite of increasing disk size. I wonder why this shows the same drop rate and what is going on internally.

[graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIeRx.png)

In the above graph, the blue line indicates the throughput and you can see that it drops when snapshot happens and you can also notice that even though the second drop phase saves the larger disk size than the first phase, the drop rate is the same. So, **my question would be is performance only affected by the private memory saving?**

Comment: You seem to be wrongly interpreting "memory used" as "size of file on disk".

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry Oh, D'oh! Thanks! I didn't realized that. I read the code again and I found that the number means "Private dirty memory". But, then again, I have another question for that. I will edit the post.